# How to fix security.xml file

Tags: java, security, websphere

So I configured my server (using the admin console) to use kerberos and everything looked fine but I didn't test the kerberos stuff yet, then I had to restart the server.  Upon restarting the server, it fails because it's trying to validate the kerberos stuff.  I just want it to startup and ignore the kerberos config.  Can I some how remove it from the security.xml file?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a standalone server and it fails to start, you can try to disable global security by editing security.xml (I think it's the attribute named "enabled" of the `<security:Security />` tag), then see if the server comes up. If it will, remove the kerberos stuff via console or wsadmin (if it won't, create a new profile - however, I guess that's not the answer you'd want to read :))

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you do this.

Turn security off via the wsadmin

You can find instructions here to do that. This is the recommended option.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173912

Alternatively, you can wade through the security.xml and change it manually but that is a risky process unless you know what to change.

After you restart you can do whatever you want to

Hope this helps
Manglu